# Chrome Extension - Access iframe Elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm appending an `iframe` to a page using `content script` with `src` set to `chrome.extension.getURL(myPage)`. Later on some event, I want to retrieve some element from the frame. I tried the following code in `content script`:

```
var textFrame = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var text = (textFrame.contentDocument || textFrame.contentWindow.document).getElementById('someDivId');
```

but it throws the following error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   chrome-extension://ipkjfhkdgodpcgpjepdjhcbfcbbbcpee/TopBar.html from
>   frame with URL http://theInjectedPage.com/xxx/xxx/xxx. Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

In `manifest` file `all_frames` is set to `true`.

Please help me to resolve this.

---

**Update:** Here is a part of my manifest file:

```
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "chrome://favicon/",
   "http://*/*", 
   "https://*/*"
 ],
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["Javascript/background.js"]
  },
 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["Javascript/References/jquery-1.7.min.js","Javascript/content_script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true
  }
 ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["TopBar.html","Javascript/TopBar.js","Javascript/References/jquery-1.7.min.js"]
```

Comment: is the code to get the element running in the content script, or background/popup.js?

Comment: its running in `content script`.

Comment: Is the html file listed as web accessible in the manifest? http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources

Comment: @Bulk - yes it is listed in `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: @NaveenBhat Hi Naveen - Just wondering if you ever found the answer to this question. Thanks . David

Comment: Don't access the iframe directly, use [cross-domain messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your permissions, but i'm just wondering why you got this error from chrome that the page TopBar.html is trying to access the frame ??
are you creating the iframe via content_script?
and what is the url you are giving to the iframe ?

you may check this code sample it injects in each page you are opening an iframe.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name":"example",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "css": [],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }]
}
```

and the **content_script.js**

```
var iframe= document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("width", "100%");
iframe.setAttribute("height", "200px;");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://gamalshaban.me/blog");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

also I've uploaded this sample extension and you can download it from this [link](http://gamalshaban.me/examples/crome-extensions/content_s.zip)

Comment: Yes, I checked that. I tried with all possible permissions that I can think of. However, this seems to me that, it is a `javascript` limitation to do cross-domain scripting. Any other workarounds?

Comment: I updated the question with a part of my manifest file. Please let me know, if I missed something in that.

Comment: ya, I'm injecting an `iframe` to the page from `content_script` like this `$('#injected-ifrmaeId').attr('src',chrome.extension.getURL(topBarPage))`

Comment: `As a side note:` When you update your answer after one day or so, please comment on the concerned person with the prefix `@` ex: `@Knvn`. Otherwise, it will not be notified to him.

Comment: @Knvn sry for the notification thing :).

Comment: @Knvn I'll update my answer with the content script and manifest codes.

Comment: thanks for your effort. However, this not solves my problem. I can inject and load the `chrome extension resource page` into an active page properly. My problem is while retrieving the contents from `iframe` on `content script`.

Comment: @Knvn i don't understand? you are trying to inject the iframe and then access it via your content script again ?

Comment: I'm appending an iframe to a page using content script. Later on some event(`mouse up` event of the page), I want to retrieve some element from the frame. [Here is my hosted extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hllpgofookedglcfhdimjhaahggbnlbe). What I'm talking is about the `in-line` feature here. Currently, I'm using `div` for this purpose and it is working fine. However, I would like to change it to `iframe` and here is where I struck with.

Comment: @Knvn nice extension, i made one like this before, you can check it [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd)here, you may call a page in your extension to set it in the src for the iframe, but remember to add this page in web_accessible_resources property in the manifest, I'll update the example with the source to call your existing popup page.