# Fill input in .mhtml file opened in Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, mhtml

I want to run e2e tests on mhtml files, i.e., fill out a form.

Viewing and extracting data works really well on the mhtml file, but I cannot fill out any `input` fields (neither manually nor via puppeteer). You can try it out with this [mhtml file](https://gist.github.com/kiwikern/b6123c4dcceefc26a1e156d94540a948) I created from the StackOverflow login page.

```
<input name="firstName" value="">
```

This is how I open the snapshot:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch()
page = await browser.newPage()
const snapshotPath = join('file://', __dirname, 'mysnapshot.mhtml')
await page.goto(snapshotPath)
```

Is there a way to fill in inputs in mhtml files or is it only possible to view them in Chrome?

Converting the snapshot to HTML works, but I want to avoid that if possible.